# Recursive Definitions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I have two recursive definitions that I need to determine if they are correct. The first one is:

The set S of all positive integer
multipliers of 5 can be described by
the following recursive definition:

$5 \in S; x \in S \rightarrow x + 5 \in
S.$ True or false.

The second one is:

Choose all of the correct recursive definitions of the set of strings formed by an odd number of 1's:

{$1, 111, 11111, 1111111, ...$}

And the choices are:

A) $1 \in S$

$X \in S \rightarrow X11 \in S$

B) $11 \in S$

$X \in S \rightarrow X11 \in S$

C) $1 \in S$

$X \in S \rightarrow X1 \in S$

D) $11 \in S$

$X \in S \rightarrow X1 \in S$

I am pretty sure that the first question is true because any positive integer + 5 should still be in $S$. For the second one, I am totally lost. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your line $S \in S; x \in S \rightarrow x + 5 \in S.$ seems nonsensical.

Comment: Ah, that's supposed to be $5 \in S$ thanks. @GEdgar

Comment: Hint. For each possible answer in the second problem, write down the first few strings that the rules tell you must be in $S$.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if I am right in saying that the first one is true?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Just work through the first few terms in the recursion until you get a sense of the pattern.

For example, let's see why option D is wrong. We know that $11 \in S$, so $(11)1 \in S$. Applying the recursive rule again, we know that $(111)1 \in S$. Likewise, $(1111)1 \in S$. So:
$$
S = \{11, 111, 1111, 11111, \ldots\}
$$
which doesn't match what we want.

Comment: Thanks for your help on that one. After doing some work, it seems like B and D are automatically ruled out because the first number in the set would be 11, which is now what I want. I also ruled out C, because that would produce {$1,11,111,1111,...$}. After working A, that seems to be correct. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yep! =] $\mathbb{}$

Comment: Thanks! The first question should be true, shouldn't it? @Adriano